# Pylint errors-only in text editor

Tags: python, sublimetext3, pylint, pylintrc

I'm using `pylint` with `Sublime Text`. I can get `pylint` to ignore certain warnings by putting the following at the top of the file.

```
# pylint: disable = some-option, another-option, a-third-option
```

I want `pylint` to disable *all* warnings in a file, not just the ones I specify. I understand that through normal use of `pylint`, I can get this behavior by using some command-line arguments. However, I am not using `pylint` on the command-line - I want my text editor to recognize this.

I can get *all* warnings ignored by including the following in `.pylintrc`:

```
[IGNORE WARNINGS]

errors-only=yes
```

However, this ignores all the warnings in the whole project, not just an individual file, and I need to remember to remove it when I am working on the other files. Furthermore, putting `pylint: disable = errors-only` at the top of a file does not do anything as I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `# pylint: disable=W,C,R` at top of a file to disable *Warning*, *Convention*, and *Refactoring* for a file.

Comment: Can you try `# pylint: disable=W,C,R` ?

Comment: Warning, Convention, and Refactoring, respectively.

Comment: Here is more about [message control](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html).